# Print site logo just on first page (@media print )

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I need to create print version of website, and as I mention in title I need to display site logo just on first page. For example, if I print home page, and I get 5 pages, logo should be displayed just on first page.

is it possible with @media print ?

**What I've tried so far** but does not work

```
@media print {
#top-menu,
#main-navigation-sticky-wrapper,
#action-bar,
.teaser-cda,
.pre-footer,
.footer,
.post-footer,
.header .logo {
    display: none;
}
@page:first {
    .header .logo { display:block }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first)) for first page is:

```
@page :first {
   /* .... */
}
```

You don't have a space between the two components. Be wary, however, as compatibility for `@page :first` is not well-defined.

It might not even be necessary though. I don't think block-level elements get repeated on every page, so you might just need to ensure that the logo is displayed in `@media print { ... }`.

You will also want to check the element and it's container elements to ensure that none of them have `position: fixed` as that may also cause the element to repeat on each printed page.

Comment: Make sense. But when I define .header .logo { display: block; } in @media print {  }, logo appear on every page again when I print the page and on print preview also. Any idea?

Comment: Does the logo (or any of it's parent elements) have other styles applied related to positioning? I think `position: fixed`, and possibly `position: absolute` might cause it to repeat on each page.

Comment: Yes, thats the clue. when I change position: fixed; to position: relative; works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @MileMijatovic I updated the answer to reflect this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@page rule is a CSS at-rule used to modify different aspects of a printed page property. It targets and modifies **only the page's dimensions, page orientation, and margins**.

**It can't have css class inside.**

@page :first {...} it just allows you to add these previous styles on the first page but you can't also add a class inside.